# jQuery: Show/Hide div on click works with webkit not mozilla

Tags: jquery, webkit, mozilla, show-hide

I've been building a site for months, and have a very basic part of the site doing a simple hide/show div. I've only been testing in Chrome, and it's been working like a dream. But today i tested out Firefox, and it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".show_hide").bind("click", doSwitch);

  function doSwitch() {
    // Get the ID out of the id="" attr of the <a>
    var ind = $(this).attr("id").replace("in", "");
    var ud = $(this).attr("id").replace("out", "");
    var pik = $(this).attr("id").replace("trigger", "");


    // Hide all the blocks, because a block has been chosen!
    $(".infobox").hide();

    // Show the requested #ID
    $("#in-"+ind).fadeIn(1);
    $("#out-"+ud).fadeIn(1);
    $("#trigger"+pik).fadeIn(1);

   return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net for testing?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? What happens if you run `$('.show_hide').click()` manually?

Comment: I'm trying to get the jsfiddle to work. But since it's filled in a ton of php, it's really hard to work it out. It's non-working on jsfiddle, but nonetheless the link is: http://jsfiddle.net/TxzbX/

Comment: @Hans Engel How do I run it manually, and how do I view the console? Bare with me, please - I'm new to js. :)

Comment: It works on JSFIDDLE if you do the following: Add a brace and closing parenthesis at the end of the code "})", and change the FRAMEWORK to "onDomReady" and "jQuery 1.6.2". Then it works on IE 9 and on Firefox.

Comment: I always debug on Firefox with FIREBUG, which finds lots of errors in my code. Try it at http://getfirebug.com/downloads - regards

Comment: +1 for Firebug in Firefox, and if you're in a WebKit browser you can use Tools -> JavaScript Console (part of the "Developer Tools").

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$(".show_hide").click(doSwitch);`

also, change `fadeIn(1)` to just `show()` it will be a lot faster instead of trying to animate it.

Comment: I tried both. Unfortunately none of it worked in Firefox, so it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".show_hide").live("click",function(){doSwitch();});
```